# How to install PyV8 in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: python, javascript

I want to install PyV8 in Ubuntu 13.04. However `pip install -v pyv8` takes super long to build and finally fails.

How can I install PyV8 on a Ubuntu 13.04 machine?

Here is the error log

`InstallationError: Command /home/x/pyv8/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/x/pyv8/build/pyv8/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-63AI25-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/x/pyv8/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/x/pyv8/build/pyv8`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a good tutorial on the web, which solves this problem:
http://andrewwilkinson.wordpress.com/2012/01/23/integrating-python-and-javascript-with-pyv8/

The steps that worked for me where a bit different though:

- `sudo apt-get install scons libboost-python-dev`
- `svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8`
- `svn checkout http://pyv8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pyv8`
- `cd v8`
- `` export V8_HOME=`pwd` ``
- `cd ../pyv8`
- `sudo python setup.py build`
- `sudo python setup.py install`

Comment: When compiling on a machine without much memory, removing `-j 8` from the `cmdline` string in pyv8/setup.py can help. (This keeps the build from running eight compiler processes in parallel.)